# Как на php обработать запрос по UDP протоколу?

Tags: php, udp

На PHP можно обрабатывать запросы по http протоколу, в этом ему помогают nginx или apache. Как с помощью PHP обрабатывать, запросы по UPD протоколу. Интересует, для написания простенького сервера для игры, которая обращается к серверу по UDP протоколу.

Comment: Вот например получение сообщения https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-recvfrom.php и дальше по теме сокетов смотрите. Еще вам понадобится https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-select.php или что то подобное, если понадобиться работать сразу с многими сокетами. Замечу, что php плохо приспособлен для подобных задач

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл, не совсем стандартное использование php. Но рабочее

https://github.com/reactphp/datagram